# Flexible palm disc sander: Are there any other names?

Tags: tools, sanding, hand-tools, terminology, sander

I came across a **hand tool** in a [This Old House/Nick Offerman video](https://youtu.be/Gh6H7Md_L2k?t=361) that is some sort of **[flexible pam disc sander](https://www.fintechabrasives.com/sanders/flexible-palm-disc-sander)**.

How it's used: I think the user can simply velcro on a hook-and-loop sanding pad (which seems quite convenient).

[image]

**Question:**

As mentioned, I am aware that ***flexible pam disc sander*** is one way of describing this tool. However, I'm not getting many hits when searching that name online.

**Are there any other names for this tool?**

Comment: The reason I ask: I'm hoping to order some to Canada, but I need to find a Canadian source first. **I can't figure out what the common name for the tool is.**

Answer (score 1):

I think "round hand sanding pad" or "round sanding block" get you there.

[Google 1](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1853&bih=950&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=0a3lW_D9DIycjwS7yY7ACw&q=round%20hand%20sanding%20pads&oq=round%20hand%20sanding%20pads&gs_l=img.3...31684.32349..32507...0.0..0.132.730.0j6......1....1..gws-wiz-img.M-H2uxKINi4) | [Google 2](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1853&bih=950&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=0a3lW_D9DIycjwS7yY7ACw&q=round%20sanding%20block&oq=round%20sanding%20block&gs_l=img.3..0.14337.16294..16465...0.0..0.136.1826.11j8......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i67j0i8i30j0i24.aAbdlSTwsC4)